# Bootstrap 3 nested rows work different in Firefox than Chrome and Explorer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox

I'm having some problems nesting rows because behaviour is different in Firefox, Chrome and Explorer.

I have two different snippets:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="sidebar affix">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="panel panel-primary">
                      Some content here
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <div class="content">
           Some other content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result in Firefox is like

[image]

Meanwhile in Chrome and Explorer 9 look like

[image]

The code seems to be well formatted. The solution I tried is change "col-md-12" to "col-md-3" but now, I have the expected results in Chrome and Explorer but not Firefox.

Is there any workaround or a way to make bootstrap use a different classes depending of the browser?

Comment: Maybe it's caused by the `affix` plugin? However, please, attach your CSS code to the question or provide a working snippet / fiddle (you can read this that helps you a lot: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ )

Comment: I'm relying in CSS not affix.js. The code is working in firefox out of the box. That's the weird thing.

Comment: Please, make a working fiddle or snippet to see the problem working, is the best

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap documentation seems contrary on this, but I find in my projects, if I want to nest rows inside other rows I also have to include an inner `.container-fluid`.

For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="sidebar affix">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                       <div class="panel panel-primary">
                          Some content here
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <div class="content">
           Some other content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I do this I don't see any rendering difference between Firefox and Chrome.